# ZF: router plugin does not work

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, router

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->setParam('useDefaultControllerAlways', true);
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->addRoute('taxes', new     Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static('taxes',
                    array('controller' => 'config', 'action' => 'taxes'))
                );
```

Does anyone know what why this does not work if called like a plugin in a bootstrap file? If called directly in a bootstrap - everything works fine. Plugin is set to work with preDispatch() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> preDispatch() is called before an action is dispatched by the
>   dispatcher. This callback allows for proxy or filter behavior.

which means that on predispatch routing has already occured , what you want is probably routeStartup because it is called before routing the request :

> routeStartup() is called before Zend_Controller_Front calls on the
>   router to evaluate the request against the registered routes.

Answer (score 0):

Because routing has already happened when preDispatch is called. You probably want to use routeStartup instead. See: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html#zend.controller.plugins.using for a full list of the controller plugin methods, in order.